# Thread in android service does not work as intended

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application which creates and starts a service. Service then creates a thread. This role of thread is to do some task and sleep for 5 seconds and then again do the task, sleep for 5 seconds and so on.

The problem I am facing is, sometime, instead of sleeping for 5 seconds, the thread doesn't wake up for up to 2 minutes. I understand Android system can do some high priority work which might cause delay in thread wake up. Is there any way I can improve it where thread always wakes up after 5 seconds.

The code for the service onCreate(). Please note that I am logging "Thread Running" with timestamp in a log file to calculate the delay.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    logger.Log("MTrackService::onCreate()");
    thMain = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(running) {
                logger.Log("Thread Running");
                try {
                    //Do Stuff
                    Thread.sleep(5*1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thMain.start();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you estimate the time elapsed between every sleep?

Comment: I checked the log file and I am writing timestamp with the word "Thread Running"

Comment: Are you sure the thread is still running didn't crash or was ended in another way? Maybe it's stuck somewhere else.

Comment: Is your use case actually involve an event every 5 seconds, or are you using a short time for debugging purposes? How long of a cycle time do you expect with the practical application?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your device is going to sleep. In that case your thread will not run every 5 seconds. It won't run again until the device wakes up.

You can verify this by keeping the device awake (use a wakelock or plug it into USB power and set the setting "don't sleep if plugged in" in the application->developer settings.

If you really need to have your thread run every 5 seconds then you will need to get a wakelock and make sure the device does not go to sleep. This will, of course, drain the battery and piss off your users ;-)